# Invalid left hand assignment error in console

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting this error in console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at changeFirstDate (script.js:156)
    at HTMLInputElement.oninput (index.html:97)
```

I double checked my codes and I can't find the problem

here is the HTML:

```
   <p>Type First Date </p>
          <input id="typefirstdate" type="text" placeholder="(example: June 1 2018)" oninput="changeFirstDate()">

   <p id="firstDate"></p>
```

and here is the JS :

```
document.getElementById('typefirstdate').addEventListener('input', changeFirstDate);

    function changeFirstDate() {
        let firstDate = document.getElementById('typefirstdate').value;
      document.getElementById('firstDate') = firstDate;
    }
```

I have read other questions similar to my problem but there seems no answer to this type of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the function to this:

```
function changeFirstDate() {
      let firstDate = document.getElementById('typefirstdate').value;
      document.getElementById('firstDate').innerHTML = firstDate;
}
```

Comment: Sure, After 6 minutes because answer button is not working

Answer (score 2):

The more general answer is :

You cannot do *something.getElementById(id) = somethingElse*

The element on the left side of the "=" cannot be affected a value because it's the anonymous result of a function execution (getElementById). Thus the error "Invalid left-hand side in assignment".

You have to use a function (accessor or other) that specifically lets you overwrite the content of the element. That's why *.innerHtml* was suggested.